# Return after response.redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have method `public void categoriesForm_DeleteItem(int categoryID)` in
 `public partial class Categories_View1 : System.Web.UI.Page` . It is modeled after method `RemoveItem` from tutorial http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/shopping-cart .

My method contains following code:

```
public void categoriesForm_DeleteItem(int categoryID)
{
    /* some code ommited */
    if (c != null)
    {
        db.Categories.Remove(c);
        db.SaveChanges();
        Response.RedirectToRoute("CategoriesList");
        //should I add return; here?
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("NotFoundError", "Category not found.");
        return;
    }
    /* code ommited */
}
```

Should I add `return;` after Response.RedirectToRoute("CategoriesList"); ?

One more question... I saw on the tutorial that the method `RemoveItem` returns **int**, what is the intent behind that return code? Where is that return code useful?

Comment: If the method ends after that `if..else` clause, then no. No need for `return`. If it not, it depends whether there will be some code in there that can clear the response or change in it some way (rare).

Comment: the sig for that method from the tutorial you linked is `public void RemoveItem(string removeCartID, int removeProductID)`, no int returned.

Comment: @DrewJordan i must have seen int return type on some other method. :/

Comment: More on Response.Redirect(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252424/asp-net-what-happens-to-code-after-response-redirect

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Should I add return; after Response.RedirectToRoute("CategoriesList"); ?

That depends on whether or not you want the code to return.

First, note a key difference between `Response.Redirect()` and `Response.RedirectToRoute()`.  The former (older) method by default aborts the thread, which throws a `ThreadAbortException`.  So no code after that statement would be expected to execute anyway.  The latter (newer) method, however, **does not**.  Which means any code after it *will* be expected to execute.

Given that, take a look at the last bit in your example...

```
/* code ommited */
```

That code will execute if you don't return from the method.  If you don't want that to happen, you would either need to return from the method or structure the code such that no further code path exists after calling `Response.RedirectToRoute()`.

Answer (score -1):

A void method does not have a return type by default. If you return an object or anything, you will have runtime error.

Comment: you can always write 'return;'